# Restrict the lightbox image size to 1200

Tags: php, image, magento

click on "product image", you can see image ,image will expand with original size [lightbox image]

I want to restrict that lightbox image size to 1200  in product view page in magento.

please see below media.phtml file

media.phtml file = http://pastebin.com/8yaDrs8Q

help me to restrict the lightbox image size for 1200.

let me know if you need any clarifications,

thanks in advance,....

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://slopjong.de/2013/04/02/lightbox2-limit-the-max-image-size/) , should help you out?

Comment: thanks that you replied..... can you please help me what code i have to change in media.phtml file using that link....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Image size has been taken through css and js file not from media.phtml.
You should change lightbox.js. Above given link clearly suggest you how to do it. If you don't want to make any changes than just follow below steps.
Just replace your lightbox.js with LightboxXL.js and css file also.

This script has built in image resize function. Download LightboxXL.js from here-->> http://www.ramirezcobos.com/labs/lightboxxl-for-prototype/

Comment: do you have any idea where is lightbox.js file in magento folders?

Comment: Location: "/var/www/html/magento/skin/frontend/default/default/YourModuleName/js " Make sure location of package according to you.

Comment: thanks, where to place the index.html file? is i have to rename this as magento usually take .phtml files?

Comment: In, Magento you cant directly put index.html. You have to put header, footer and wrapper to their appropriate .phtml file. Those files located here-->> /var/www/html/magento/app/design/frontend/rwd/custom_theme/template/page/